# Kotlin callbackFlow - awaitClose is not called as expected

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to wrap callback and convert it into flow. After the flow is completed, it should trigger `awaitClose` block and then unregister listener. However, `awaitClose` doesn't work as I expected.
What I did wrong here?

```
fun main() {
   runBlocking {
       println("runBlocking on ${Thread.currentThread()}")
       getLocationFlow()
           .collect { location ->
               println("Collect location [${location.lat}, ${location.lon}] on ${Thread.currentThread()}")
           }
       println("runBlocking end")
   }
}

fun getLocationFlow(): Flow<Location> {
    return callbackFlow<Location> {
        val locationListener = object : LocationListener {
            override fun onLocationUpdate(location: Location) {
                println("onLocationUpdate: [${location.lat}, ${location.lon}] on ${Thread.currentThread()}")
                trySend(location)
            }

        }
        LocationManager.registerForLocation(locationListener)

        // NOT CALL AS EXPECTED
        awaitClose {
            LocationManager.unregisterForLocation(locationListener)
            println("awaitClose called")
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)
}

object LocationManager {

    fun registerForLocation(locationListener: LocationListener) {
        println("registerForLocation on ${Thread.currentThread()}")
        (0..5).forEach {
            locationListener.onLocationUpdate(Location(it.toLong(), it*2L))
        }
    }

    fun unregisterForLocation(locationListener: LocationListener) {
        println("unregisterForLocation on ${Thread.currentThread()}")
    }
}

data class Location(
    val lat: Long,
    val lon: Long
)

interface LocationListener {
    fun onLocationUpdate(location: Location)
}
```

And here is the log:

`runBlocking on Thread[main,5,main] registerForLocation on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] onLocationUpdate: [0, 0] on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] onLocationUpdate: [1, 2] on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] onLocationUpdate: [2, 4] on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] onLocationUpdate: [3, 6] on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] onLocationUpdate: [4, 8] on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] onLocationUpdate: [5, 10] on Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main] Collect location [0, 0] on Thread[main,5,main] Collect location [1, 2] on Thread[main,5,main] Collect location [2, 4] on Thread[main,5,main] Collect location [3, 6] on Thread[main,5,main] Collect location [4, 8] on Thread[main,5,main] Collect location [5, 10] on Thread[main,5,main]`

I'm trying to wrap callback and convert it into `Flow` using `callbackFlow`. `awaitClose` block should be called when the `flow` is completed and then unregister the callback. However, `awaitClose` is not called as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see where you are completing the flow anywhere.

A callback flow is infinite, so it will never complete normally when you call `collect()` on it. To complete it, you must either cancel the coroutine that's collecting, or use the `take()` operator on it before collection to turn it into a finite flow, for example:

```
fun main() {
   runBlocking {
       println("runBlocking on ${Thread.currentThread()}")
       getLocationFlow()
           .take(2) // Now it is finite and will complete after 2 items are emitted
           .collect { location ->
               println("Collect location [${location.lat}, ${location.lon}] on ${Thread.currentThread()}")
           }
       println("runBlocking end")
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you can call `first()` on it, which collects the first item and completes it.